# BSOD 0xc000000e - Is this SSD drive broken?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bsod

I have SSD drive connected via M2 in my laptop (GL552VW). Once the computer has frozen and now every time it gives me BSOD with 0xc000000e.

I tried to repair it like that:

[image: See console output]

But it didn't work...

I tried to list disks to see if it is detected:

[image: See console output]

It seems it detects this SandForce (but with some ridiculous size, should be around ~500GB).

Questions:
1) **Can I be sure that this SSD is broken**? There's no hope for it?
2) **Can I somehow copy some files from it?**

Comment: You can try some of these commands: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872425.aspx. If it somehow still does not work I would suggest trying out the SSD with another computer to see if it works.

Comment: Might also look at "sandforce panic mode" and see if the symptoms match.

Comment: @Yorik How can I check that the drive is in "panic mode"? Google doesn't seem to say a lot about it, besides that after hibernating some controllers bricks (but I weren't using any sleep/hibernation).

Comment: @Bungicasse I will check that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend using [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html) to examine the drive's SMART status. Pay attention to SMART 05h Reallocated Sector Count, C6h Uncorrectable Error Count, and maybe something named End-to-End Error Rate. These entries are not specific to SandForce drives. If any of them shows a large value, then your drive is doomed. Data recovery from a broken SSD is extremely unlikely.

Have you tried repartitioning and reformatting it in Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc)? Did it report error? (bootrec is a higher level utility compared to diskmgmt)

Comment: From what I see CrystalDiskInfo is a Windows GUI application. I'm not sure how to run it if I cannot boot Windows. Are there any Windows able to run from pendrive (like Linux)? 
And I haven't formatted the disk yet as I still hope for some data recovery.

Comment: @zupazt3 Try searching WinPE. When investigating PCs that won't start, I always use ISO images from www.laomaotao.net (sorry but it's in Chinese) to make my USB stick bootable. It boots into a fully-fledged Win 10 desktop.